# Shadows under windows in Ubuntu: How are they accomplished?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, x11, compiz

There are shadows under all the windows in Ubuntu. My question is, is this done through X11, Compiz, GTK+, or otherwise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shadows are drawn by your window manager. This is probably Compiz in your case, but Metacity also draws shadows.